# It is irritating me. It is irritating to me

Tags: word-usage, differences, prepositions, adjectives

It is irritating me. 
It is irritating to me. 
Which one is correct? 
Does the word "irritating" work as an  adjective in my second one sentence?

Comment: Both are correct. Have you tried a dictionary? Some research is expected when asking a question. A dictionary will usually correctly identify the function(s) of the word.

Comment: I didn't check it in my dictionary.  In fact,  I  was confused here.  I wanted to take guidance from you.

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/irritating

Comment: The first sentence, you are being irritated by something. The second sentence, you think something is irritating.

Comment: You are respectfully requested to make me understand with good design. I mean to say, Share your thoughts or point of views concerning my sentences. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is irritating me.

"Irritating" here is a verb - something is making you irritated.

> It is irritating **to** me.

Something is of irritating nature to *you*.

Comment: It is irritating to me. Sir, in this sentence does the word "irritating " work as an adjective?

Comment: Yes, it does. In the first, you can say, for instance, that something is irritating your skin. In the second you can say that a particular song is irritating to you.